# integral basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt a, \sqrt b)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I have a question regarding this.

Let $ gcd(a,b) = 1$, $K_1 := \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt a)$, $K_2 := \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt b)$

$\{1, \theta\}$ is the integral basis of $\mathbf{O}_{K_1}$(Ring of integers of $K_1$) and

$\{1,\theta^{'}\} $ is the integral basis of $\mathbf{O}_{K_2}$ (Ring of integers of $K_2$)

futher more let

$K := \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt a, \sqrt b)$ and $\mathbf{O}_{K}$ is the ring of integers of $K$

I don't understand, why you can write every $\alpha \in \mathbf{O}_{K}$ as

$\alpha = 1 \cdot \beta_1 + \theta \cdot \beta_2$ where $\beta_i \in \mathbb{Q}[\theta^{'}]$

I am new to algebraic number theory so I don't have any clue how to tackle this problem.

Comment: My guess is that at this point you are just using the fact that $1,\theta,\theta',\theta\theta'$ is a $\Bbb{Q}$-basis for $K$. So every element of $K$ can be written in this way. What is not clear whether you can restrict $\beta_i$s to come from $\Bbb{Z}[\theta']$ when $\alpha$ is integral.

Comment: ko I understand, so basically  let $ \beta_1 = q_1 + q_2 \theta^{'}, \beta_2 = q_2 + q_3 \theta^{'}$ and I have the representation as a \mathbb{Q}-basis. thank you.

Comment: Correct. Well done!